# Enum Types in Marshalled struct produce incorrect offsets for Marshall.OffsetOf

Tags: c#, struct, enums, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a type that I'm trying to populate from some C code. However I'm getting some really weird behaviour when trying to calculate the byte offsets whenever I have an enum type as part of the structure.

In this example you can see that I've specified all fields should start with a byte offset of 0 (pretend the C type is a union). I have two defined enums, one of size int, one of size byte.

```
{
    public enum ByteEnum : byte { }
    public enum IntEnum : int { }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct UserData
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int i1;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public long l1;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public IntEnum intEnum;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int i2;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int i3;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public ByteEnum byteEnum;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int i4;
    }
}
```

As such when I call

```
Marshal.OffsetOf(type, fieldInfo.Name)
```

I would expect it to return 0 for all fields, as I have explicitly set that as all field offsets.

In reality this is my output:

```
UserData
i1 : 0
l1 : 0
intEnum : 0
i2 : 4
i3 : 4
byteEnum : 4
i4 : 5
```

Notice that after every enumeration field, OffsetOf keeps returning 0 + sizeof(enum field). This is causing me to get the completely wrong byte offsets for my C structures. I have no idea why this is happening? Any thoughts? Is there something in particular about the enum class am I missing which causes this behaviour? Thanks in advance

Comment: @this It's pretty clearly C#.

Comment: @this I think the asker added the C tag because they are asking about interoperability with C. However, the question is really about C#, so you correctly removed the C tag.

Comment: The C tag was already removed, so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @Jashaszun yes that is why I tagged it C, thanks for fixing it though

Comment: Your example doesn't even work for me. It fails with "Could not load type 'UserData' from assembly .. because it contains an object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field." If you get rid of the `string` field `s2` then it works as you expected.

Comment: I don't hit this issue personally, but for the sake of clarity here I'll edit it to remove the string. Just to check by 'works as you expected' you mean, still with the byte offset issue?

Comment: @MattNewcombe without the string "OffsetOf" returns zero for all fields.

Comment: Since it might be relevant, what version of the CLR are you targeting?

Comment: Well that's really weird, I'm definitely not seeing that, the problem exists for me as stated @vcsjones :(

Comment: Nope. Can't reproduce it. I tried various different versions of the CLR. Something else is going on. Here is an online example: https://ideone.com/e0xIYu - you need to create a concise example that can be fully reproduced. Your code as written required my to make some assumptions, like how you are using OffsetOf.

Comment: I doubt anybody is going to repro this problem, my crystal ball says that you are using Mono.  There [was a known bug](http://marc.info/?l=mono-bugs&m=126427689223575&w=2) that resembles it strongly.  File this bug with whatever organization or project that's appropriate, we can't fix it for you.

Comment: Your crystal ball is 100% correct, looks like it is a compiler issue, I'll raise it there, thanks!